# Two separate Tables of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to have two separate Tables of Contents, which share only one chapter, like this:

Table of Contents - Statistics

Introduction .......1

Probability .......10

Random Variables...20

Table of Contents - Geometry

Introduction .......1

Curves.............50

Surfaces...........60

I tried various methods, but I finally gave up after hours of trying. Could someone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `setcounter{page}{...}` are only for demo here.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}% for unnumbered sections
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}   % for unnumbered sections
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Table of Contents -- Statistics}{}}

\newpage\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Introduction}

\newpage\setcounter{page}{10}
\section{Probability}

\newpage\setcounter{page}{20}
\section{Random Variables}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Table of Contents -- Geometry}{}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{1}}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\numberline {}Introduction}{1}}% for an unnumbered section

\newpage\setcounter{page}{50}
\section{Curves}

\newpage\setcounter{page}{60}
\section{Surfaces}

\end{document}
```

[image]