# Remove the same chapter and figures as before from Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, chapters

I have a chapter with sections and figures but now, I need the same chapter but translated to Spanish. What I did, in the same .tex, was to copy the content and paste after, i.e.

```
\chapter{Conclusions}
...
\section{...}
...
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{...}
\caption{...}
\end{figure}
...

\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}
\chapter{Conclusiones}
...
\section{...}
...
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{...}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\caption{...}
\end{figure}
...
```

I set `\addtocounter{}{}` to have the same numbering. However, this second part translated it shows in Table of Contents (ToC). I want to remove it from ToC without using, for instance, `\chapter*{}` or `\caption*{}` because I need to display the same numbering as before. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be odd if the Spanish sections were not mentioned at all? Maybe you could do something along the lines of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110296/194703.

Comment: It was useful to me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
```

at an appropriate point in your document will stop chapters being listed in the ToC.  Similarly for figures `{lof}` instead of `{toc}` and tables `{lot}` instead of `{toc}`.